# Hill-top villages to escape the heat south of Florence

Tags: italy, weather-and-climate, destinations, tuscany

We will be visiting halfway between Florence and Siena (Italy) at the end of August. It is going to be very hot I expect so I am looking for high villages/towns we can visit to get some cool.

My first instinct was to try to find an altitude map of the area but I haven't had any luck yet.

Can anyone recommend some villages/towns in the area which are interesting and will be cooler on very hot days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

San Gimignano and Volterra are the usual suspects concerning hilltop villages in the area. They aren't that high up though and I'm not sure it will be that much cooler and (especially the first) will be full of tourists.

Otherwise you could do as the Italians do and head towards the sea. If you want to escape the heat in the altitude your best guess is the ["Alpi Apuane"](http://www.parks.it/parco.alpi.apuane/Eiti.php) north of Lucca (but that is best done with a car).

Comment: Thank you. We will have a car so could you recommend some places in the mountains to visit?

Comment: This might be a starting point: http://www.parcapuane.toscana.it/turismo/itinerari_sez.asp?id=16 or this one (less detailed but in English) http://www.parks.it/parco.alpi.apuane/Eiti.php

Answer (score 3):

I have visited various cities in Tuscany from Florence, and i suggest the following trips to visit.

My favorites hill towns are:

1. San Gimignano
2. Montereggioni (appears assasins creed 2 story)
3. Cortona
4. Montalcino
5. Volterra

When you are in tuscan sun..

1. Dont miss cypress trees (they shot gladiator movie there). These trees are wind breakers.
2. Sip of tuscan red wines.

**Useful links**

http://www.tuscanychic.com/traveling-in-tuscany/tuscanys-most-beautiful-hilltop-villages
https://www.ricksteves.com/watch-read-listen/read/articles/hill-towns-of-central-italy
http://www.calgaryherald.com/travel/five+must+italian+hill+towns+tuscany+umbria/9787100/story.html

Comment: I would avise against drinking wine in the heat.